# Can ElasticSearch accept pre-tokenized content and return the corresponding tf-idf score?

Tags: elasticsearch

I got some Chinese material, which has been finely tokenized with a field-specific tokenizer. So I preprocess them by adding space between tokens and want to put them into es cluster. I expect es can calculate idf of these documents without using its default Chinese tokenizer, and return the corresponding score. Does es support this? I just want to take advantage of the fantastic performance of es, not its own tokenizer!

Comment: ES supports custom analyzers / tokenizers or no analyzer. I’d check the docs in the analyzers portion

Comment: @bryan60 Yeah... I found the whitespace tokenizer, which might be what I need. What I worried about before is that if I don't use the analyzers es supplies, es will stop idf calculation

Comment: it definitely will still calculate idf / tf etc. That's all index time config.

Answer (score 0):

When u chose a mapping type that is [analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) e.g. text elastic search will generate a score for your query. In your case you can use the [whitespace](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html) analyzer in the mapping of the index.